# Replace substrings with HTML element (Fill the blanks type question)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to create a "fill the blanks" type of questions.

```
const fill = ['ABC', 'XYZ'] 
const string = ['Lorem ipsum dolor ABC sit amet consectetur XYZ'];
```

The goal: Replace ABC andd XYZ with HTML input fields and return text/html.

Tried various approaches with `split` and `replace`. Having trouble to correctly assemble the strings again. I.e.

```
var final = "";
fill.forEach((element) => {
  final += string.replace(element, inputField);
});

console.log(final);
```

Solution should also be flexible enough to deal with an unknown number of items in the `fill` array.

Comment: Is there a reason your `string` variable is an _array_ and not a single _string_? What is the expected output when you have multiple strings in this array?

Comment: Arrays don't have a `replace()` method, only strings do.

Comment: you're replacing each item in `fill` with the same `inputField`. Is that really what you want?

Comment: Your code already deals with an arbitrary number of items in `fill`.

Comment: @NickParsons, no reason really for the ```string``` variable to be in an array. Expected output is a string where the matched substrings from the ```fill``` variable are replaced with input fields.

Comment: The second argument to the `forEach` callback function is the array index. You can use that to index into a collection of input fields.

Comment: Since you're doing `final +=` you'll get multiple copies of the input string, each one with a different substring replaced.

Comment: You could also use the `fill` element as the ID of the input field. `string.replace(element, document.getElementById(element).value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want;

```
replaceToHTMLInput = function (str, replaceArr) {
    replaceArr.forEach(x=>str=str.replace(new RegExp("\\b" + x + "\\b","g"), " <input id='" + x + "'/> ")); 
    return str; 
}

replaceToHTMLInput("Lorem ipsum dolor ABC sit amet consectetur XYZ", ["ABC", "XYZ"])

"Lorem ipsum dolor  <input id='ABC'/>  sit amet consectetur  <input id='XYZ'/> "
```